# Jenkins Workflow and NUnit Test Results

Tags: jenkins, junit, nunit, jenkins-workflow

I'm currently using Jenkins Workflow with a project that is producing NUnit test results.

I've tried using a simple build step to archive these test results

```
step([$class: "JUnitResultArchiver", artifacts: "Test-Results/**/*.*"])
```

Unfortunately it seems the JUnit archiver is unable to parse the XML produced by `nunit-console`, it outputs that the file contains no results. I'm guessing this is because there are differences between JUnit and NUnit in terms of the XML schema (I probably should have realized this).

The Jenkins NUnit plugin is able to parse the file but it seems the plugin isn't yet implementing the simple build step required for it to be used with Workflow.

Has anyone found a way to get this working or do we have to wait for the NUnit plugin to be made Workflow friendly?

Answer (score 2):

Transform the the nunit result file  "TestResult.xml", using the below command.

`bat '"h:\\tools\\msxsl.exe" "TestResult.xml" "nunit-to-junit.xsl" -o JUnitLikeNunitResults.xml'`

you can download the `"msxsl.exe"` from the MS site, for the `"nunit-to-junit.xsl"` you can grab it from the nunit test publishing plugin for jenkins [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/nunit-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/nunit).

Once this is done, use the `step` to publish 
`step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: 'JUnitLikeNunitResults.xml'])`

Comment: I would suggest using NUnit 3 build-in convertion `--OPTION:filename;format=formatname` described in https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

Answer (score 1):

I used [nunit3-xunit transform](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-transforms/tree/master/nunit3-junit) in generation of my unit test report and then was able to use junit publish step in pipeline plug in.

Comment: This XSLT spec was great and it worked natively with nunit3-console's result / transform option. Ended up with a command like 'nunit3-console.exe someproj.csproj --config=Debug --result="artifacts\test-result.xml;transform=nunit3-junit.xslt"'. Note the quotes around the "result" option are required, otherwise powershell was interpreting it as two commands due to the semi-colon. I am actually using Gitlab not Jenkins but this answer got it working in that platform as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unless NUnit itself can be configured to produce JUnit-style output (I have no idea offhand), or you can manually translate results, you would need to wait for Workflow compatibility for the NUnit (and/or more generic XUnit) plugins.