# Gitlab CI not displaying Nunit test results

Tags: junit, gitlab-ci, nunit

I would like to ask since ChatGPT nor Bard can help me with this. It seems to be too specific problem.

I have this snipped in my pipeline

```
test-job:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Starting tests..."
    - echo "Using artifacts from the build-job..."
    - nuget install NUnit.ConsoleRunner -Version 3.12.0 -source https://artifactory.randomlink.com/artifactory/api/nuget/di_nuget -OutputDirectory .\NUnit
    - .\NUnit\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.12.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe .\MyProject\MyProjectTests\bin\Debug\net48\MyProjectTests.dll --result=TestResults\nunit-results.xml 
    - echo "NUnit tests completed..."
  tags:
    - WINDOWS-DOCKER 
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - .\TestResults\nunit-results.xml
    reports:  
      junit: .\TestResults\nunit-results.xml
```

This piece of code seems to be running OK. I get the test results in console. In my case there are some failed unit tests (all of them are unit). I get something like 217 tests passes 7 failed. This is OK.

I am having troubles with showing the statistics under Pipelines in "Tests" tab.

I already tried dotnet version of script but I had no better result.

[image]

I can see the report in artifacts and it seems to be OK

Can you please help me with that?

PS: These are .NET unit Tests

**EDIT:**
Log says this:

> Uploading artifacts...
> .\TestResults\nunit-results.xml: found 1 matching artifact files and directories
> Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=155474407 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_pUqPn

**EDIT2:**
XML report is in NUnit format

Comment: What does the job logs say?

Comment: What's the content of the XML report? Is that JUnit format? I don't know NUnit but Gitlab CI only accepts JUnit format.

Comment: @GaëlJ it is NUnit format. That is what I was thinking about. I should convert NUnit format to JUnit, but this is what I dont know how to do

Comment: This project seems to provide some solutions but it's archived: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-transforms

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33614171/5747944) will help answer your question about getting junit formatted output.